# Comparison between two capture groups inside condition input of IIS web.config rewrite rule

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I'm trying to compare two capture groups inside a condition input of a rewrite url in an IIS web.config.

I need to do this because I don't want users to access language specific URLs (/en/path for example) if their language code cookie does not match the language in the URL.

I've tried to achieve with this rule in my webconfig but it seems that it can't be done like this because the server answers with a 500.52 error:

```
The expression "^((?!{C:2}).)*$" contains a repeat expression (one of '*', '?', '+', '{' in most contexts) that is not preceded by an expression.
```

It is taking my {C:2} as a part of the regex itself and not a raw string.

This is the complete rule:

```
<rule name="redirect-with-lang" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="en\/|es\/|mx\/" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="langpref=\w{2}\/(\w{2});" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(\/es\/|\/en\/|\/mx\/).+$" />
        <add input="{C:1}" pattern="^((?!{C:2}).)*$"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/{C:1}/{C:3}" />
    </rule>
```

I want to know if I can achieve this in another way without resorting to javascript, or some server code at Global.asax.

Thanks

Comment: The regex pattern should only contain regex, not the placeholders you may use in the redirect rules.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, as I wrote, it seems that pattern attribute only accepts regex and not placeholders. That is why I ask for another way to achieve this in the web.config.

Comment: You should explain what the pattern should *match* then, and what result must be.

Comment: Also, no need escaping `/` char, it is not special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this  `<add input="{C:1}" pattern="^((?!\{C:2\}).)*$"/>` condition instead of `<add input="{C:1}" pattern="^((?!{C:2}).)*$"/>`

you are getting this error because of the curly brackets – { } in condition.